# Django: How to get yester query set in class-based views?

Tags: django-class-based-views, django-generic-views, django-1.4

Django: How to get yester query set in class-based views?

http://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/1.4/django.views.generic.dates/TodayArchiveView/

I use TodayArchiveView.

BTW, if TodayArchiveView get None, TodayArchiveView.as_view() raise Http404.

In this situation, I want to push data at yesterday in current model(table)...

What should I do?

Some Code Here:

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from crm.views import *

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^workDailyRecord/$', workDailyRecord),
)
```

views.py

```
from django.views.generic import TodayArchiveView
from django.http import Http404
from crm.models import *

def workDailyRecord(request):
    if request.method === 'GET':
        tView.as_view() # I want call class-based generic views at this line.
    elif:
        try:
            return tView.as_view()(request)
        except Http404:
            # I want to push data at yesterday in 'WorkDailyRecord' model
            pass

class tView(TodayArchiveView):
    model = WorkDailyRecord
    context_object_name = 'workDailyRecord'
    date_field = 'date'
    template_name = "workDailyRecord.html"
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models

class WorkDailyRecord(models.Model):
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    contents = models.TextField()
```

Comment: TodayArchiveView have some methods like get_previous_day() and get_day.

Comment: But I don't know usage of that methods. Plase help me! Thx!